# FileNotFoundException when using FileStream to Encrypt

Tags: c#, encryption

I am using C# in a Visual Studio Windows form application to write a program that can encrypt and decrypt files. I am following this walkthrough: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/Aa964697(v=VS.85).aspx  and have everything completed with some minor changes made to my environment and preferences.

When I try to encrypt a file I am given a 'FileNotFoundException was unhandled' error when the program tries to use a filestream to encrypt the file. Everything up to that point seems to be working.

Here is the code for the EncryptFile method:

```c#
private void EncryptFile(string inFile)
{
    // Create an instance of Rijndael for symmetric encryption of the data.
    RijndaelManaged rjndl = new RijndaelManaged();
    rjndl.KeySize = 256;
    rjndl.BlockSize = 256;
    rjndl.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    ICryptoTransform transform = rjndl.CreateEncryptor();

    // Use RSACryptoServiceProvider to enrypt the Rijndael key.
    byte[] keyEncrypted = rsa.Encrypt(rjndl.Key, false);

    // Create byte arrays to contain the length values of the key and IV.
    byte[] LenK = new byte[4];
    byte[] LenIV = new byte[4];

    int lKey = keyEncrypted.Length;
    LenK = BitConverter.GetBytes(lKey);
    int lIV = rjndl.IV.Length;
    LenIV = BitConverter.GetBytes(lIV);

    // Write the following to the FileStream for the encrypted file (outFs):
    // - length of the key
    // - length of the IV
    // - ecrypted key
    // - the IV
    // - the encrypted cipher content

    // Change the file's extension to ".enc"
    string outFile = EncrFolder + inFile.Substring(0, inFile.LastIndexOf(".")) + ".enc";

    using (FileStream outFs = new FileStream(outFile, FileMode.Create))
    {
        outFs.Write(LenK, 0, 4);
        outFs.Write(LenIV, 0, 4);
        outFs.Write(keyEncrypted, 0, lKey);
        outFs.Write(rjndl.IV, 0, lIV);

        // Now write the cipher text using a CryptoStream for encrypting.
        using (CryptoStream outStreamEncrypted = new CryptoStream(outFs, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            // By encrypting a chunk at a time, you can save memory and accommodate large files.
            int count = 0;
            int offset = 0;

            // blockSizeBytes can be any arbitrary size.
            int blockSizeBytes = rjndl.BlockSize / 8;
            byte[] data = new byte[blockSizeBytes];
            int bytesRead = 0;

            using (FileStream inFs = new FileStream(inFile, FileMode.Open))
            {
                do
                {
                    count = inFs.Read(data, 0, blockSizeBytes);
                    offset += count;
                    outStreamEncrypted.Write(data, 0, count);
                    bytesRead += blockSizeBytes;
                }
                while (count > 0);
                inFs.Close();
            }
            outStreamEncrypted.FlushFinalBlock();
            outStreamEncrypted.Close();
        }
        outFs.Close();
    }
}
```

The error happens at the line "using (FileStream inFs = new FileStream(inFile, FileMode.Open))".
Here is an image of the error:

[image]

What is causing the error and what is the fix?

Comment: I suspect the problem is that the file was not found. What's mysterious about that?

Comment: Also, when reporting exceptions, always post the full exception including any inner exceptions. For troubleshooting purposes only, catch the exception (maybe at the top level of your method), then post the result of `ex.ToString()`.

Comment: Forgive me I am new to all of this. I guess my problem seems simple but I am new to both programming and this site so I don't have the greatest grasp of everything. When I select the file to encrypt, why does the program look for the file elsewhere? How do I have the file where it is expected to be just from selecting the file to be used from an openfiledialog?

Comment: New or not, a "file not found" shows you the path that was being searched for the file. Go look at that path. Do _you_ find the file? No? Then neither will .NET.

Comment: What determines where it will look for the file. How do I change this? It is confusing because I assume that it should just read from the file I choose to encrypt and go from there. So then why does it expect the file to be in one place when I selected the specific file to be used?

Comment: Ok, I'm confused. Didn't you look at the image you posted? It says "Could not find file H:\CSC272\CryptBit\CryptBit\CryptBit\bin\Debug\topsecret.txt". Does that file exist at that location?

Comment: It uses the value of `inFile`. Did you read [`FileStream` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47ek66wy.aspx)?

Comment: No, the file does not exist at that location. I understand that I am getting the filenotfoundexception because the file is not there. What I do not understand is why the program is looking for the file there. I can put the file there manually and see what happens but I would rather figure out how to point to the file to be used. My question is why is it looking for the file in that location and is there a way to change where it is looking.

Comment: What is the value of `inFile` at that point in time? Have you used the debugger and set a breakpoint? If not, then do it now. If you don't know how to use the debugger, then learn it now. There is no excuse for not being able to set simple breakpoints, and no excuse for not having done so.

Comment: I select which file to use by having a click button event:

Comment: I select which file to use by having a click button event open a openfiledialog box and selecting which file I want to use. The problem seems to be that the file selected from the openfiledialog is not the filepath it is using in the actual EncryptFile method. I will work on this some more and look into it and come back. You are right that the value of inFile is wrong, I am just not understanding how to get it to be the correct value through using the openfiledialog and selecting the file I want to use.

Comment: If the file does not exist, then the OpenFileDialog cannot open it. If the dialog opens a file, then it's the wrong file  .

Answer (score 0):

you may overthink this line :

```
string outFile = EncrFolder + inFile.Substring(0, inFile.LastIndexOf(".")) + ".enc";
```

(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx)